# How do you connect a DatagramSocket server and client outside of a local area network(LAN)?

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, server, datagram

I am able to connect my DatagramSocket server and client inside my local area network(LAN) but I am unable outside of it.

Here is my code:

**GameServer class:**

```
public class GameServer extends Thread {

private DatagramSocket socket;

public GameServer() {
    try {
        this.socket = new DatagramSocket(7081,InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        try {
            socket.receive(packet);
            if(new String(packet.getData()).trim().equalsIgnoreCase("ping")){
                sendData("pong".getBytes(),packet.getAddress(),packet.getPort());
            }
            System.out.println(new String(packet.getData()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public void sendData(byte[] data, InetAddress ipAddress, int port) {

        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ipAddress, port);
        try {
            this.socket.send(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

}
```

**GameClient class:**

```
public class GameClient extends Thread {

private InetAddress ipAddress;
private DatagramSocket socket;

public GameClient(String ipAddress) {
    try {
        this.socket = new DatagramSocket();
        this.ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        try {
            socket.receive(packet);
            System.out.println(new String(packet.getData()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public void sendData(byte[] data) {

        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, ipAddress, 7081);
        try {
            socket.send(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

**RunClient class:**

```
public class RunClient {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GameClient client = new GameClient("/*Here is my external ip address*/"); //If i am running this for LAN then 192.168.1.67 and localhost work
    client.start();
    client.sendData("ping".getBytes());
}
}
```

**RunServer class:**

```
public class RunServer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GameServer server = new GameServer();
    server.start();
}
}
```

**Here are my port forwarding configurations:**

[image: Here are my port forwarding configurations]

**Some additional information:**
My local ip address is `192.168.1.67`
The port I am using is `7081`
When I check my ip and port at http://www.canyouseeme.org it gave me the following error:

```
Error: I could not see your service on "my external ip" on port (7081)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem in your code. That site (http://www.canyouseeme.org) must be trying with TCP instead of UDP.

Answer (score 0):

Please add exception for the port 7081 into firewall, so that it allow incoming connections on port.

when you are trying in LAN the IP might be different, when you are trying outside, you have to try with the external ip, which should be configured to redirect the request to your localip.

Thanks,
Ankireddy Polu